# ASP.net saving Gridview to xls error thread aborted

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

Having problems saving my Gridview to file and then downloading to the browser.

My code works on localhost, even though i get an exception thrown: Thread was being aborted.

When i publish my website to my server, i get the error: 
The given path's format is not supported.

```
protected void btn_SaveToFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string path = Server.MapPath("~/Sheets/");
    if (!Directory.Exists(path)) {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }
    try {
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter()) {
            using (HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw)) {
                StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(path + DateTime.Now +".xls");
                GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
                writer.WriteLine(sw.ToString());
                writer.Close();
                Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+DateTime.Now+ ".xls");
                Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Sheets/"+DateTime.Now+".xls"));
                Response.End();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        Debug.WriteLine("Error saving to file: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: If its possible to download an .xls directly to the browser, without saving to  server first, that would be preferred.

Comment: Does the website user account have rights to create the Sheets directory and add files to it?

Comment: The folder Sheets gets created, but no files inside on my FTP folder.But there must be a problem with the code as I am getting Thread was being aborted, even on localhost.

Comment: The given path's format is not supported. seems to be the problem why my file is not created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a whole bunch of errors. I'm not sure that it will work but try something like this:

```
//edited version
protected void btn_SaveToFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //string path = Server.MapPath("~/Sheets/");
    //if (!Directory.Exists(path)) {
    //    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    //}
    string fname=DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss")+".xls";
    try {
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter()) {
            using (HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw)) {
                //StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(path + fname);
                GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
                //writer.WriteLine(sw.ToString());
                //writer.Close();
                Response.Clear();
                Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+fname);
                //Response.TransmitFile(path+fname));
            Response.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.End();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        Debug.WriteLine("Error saving to file: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

As well, as commented before, it is better to send response directly to browser that is write to Response.

Edit: This won't produce error but the downloaded file will be .xls by extension only. Better approach is to read the GrdView per line and put whatever you need to CSV. And content type will be "text/csv". I don't want to rewrite the application. You need to do it yourself.

Comment: it worked by replacing the : and / but still having a thread being aborted

Answer (score 0):

The webhost i am using has a different way of posting `DateTime.Now`

Visual Studio was saving my file to as dd.mm.yyy hh.mm.ss
but my webhost was showing m/dd/yy h:mm:ss
/ and : are not supported as filenames.